# converting datetime in varchar and using it in where clause in Sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, varchar

This is a sql query that i am working on. It is dumping the filtered result in a temp table
it is giving an error stating "Incorrect syntax near ','."

Query.

```
DECLARE @year VARCHAR(50)
SET @year = '2012'
SELECT 
              [DAGName]
              , CONVERT(DATETIME, convert(VARCHAR(10), [ReportDate], 103), 103) AS FilteredDate        
                      INTO TempData FROM MailboxDatabase
        WHERE (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [ReportDate], 103)
        IN ( '01/01/'+ @year +,'01/02/'+ @year +,
             '01/03/'+ @year +,'01/04/'+ @year +,
             '01/05/'+ @year +,'01/06/'+ @year +,
             '01/07/'+ @year +,'01/08/'+ @year +,
             '01/09/'+ @year +,'01/10/'+ @year +,
             '01/11/'+ @year +,'01/12/'+ @year +
            ))
```

The error is coming in where condition in which I am trying to filter result on the basis of date by converting it into varchar. but it is not working .

Comment: Why specifying `+` . Remove that and you are good to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are concatenating the string in a wrong way.

try this

```
'01/01/'+ @year ,'01/02/'+ @year ,
```

Comment: yes @ARS it was the dynamic query i have made previouly now i have removed extra +... it worked one more question........

Comment: I want to get the name of the month from the temp table that i am making so I tried this SELECT DATENAME(month, FilteredDate) AS 'Month Name' it is giving synatax error.... any suggestion

Comment: It should work. I think there is some problem with the data. Check the data in filtereddate column

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @year VARCHAR(50)
SET @year = '2012'
SELECT 
              [DAGName]
              , CONVERT(DATETIME, convert(VARCHAR(10), [ReportDate], 103), 103) AS FilteredDate        
                      INTO TempData FROM MailboxDatabase
        WHERE (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [ReportDate], 103)
        IN ( '01/01/'+ @year ,'01/02/'+ @year,
             '01/03/'+ @year,'01/04/'+ @year,
             '01/05/'+ @year,'01/06/'+ @year,
             '01/07/'+ @year,'01/08/'+ @year,
             '01/09/'+ @year,'01/10/'+ @year,
             '01/11/'+ @year,'01/12/'+ @year
            ))
```

Answer (score -1):

In Microsoft SQL Server:

```
--
-- Create test case
--
DECLARE @myDateTime DATETIME
SET @myDateTime = '2013-05-07'

--
-- Convert string
--
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @myDateTime, 120), 10)
```

Comment: it is not what i am looking for, I want the where condition to be filtered out without considering the time part....

Comment: I'm sorry. It's my mistake.